# How to disabe the beep in Octave 3.8.0 GUI on Windows 7

Tags: octave

The octave 3.8.0 experimental GUI is producing a warning beep in the console if, e.g. tab is pressed and there's no unique way to continue the typed command. How do I disable this beep?

Under 3.6.4, this seem to have worked with `set bell-style none`, but this command is only producing

```
error: invalid conversion from string to real N-d array
error: set: expecting graphics handle as first argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question has been confirmed as a bug and was answered in [this Octave Bug tracker](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42268) post, which redirects to [this](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Octave-Msys-Beep-Disable-on-WIndows-td4656885.html) forum post. Quoting the answer given by JasonNicholson as-is:

> The key is that the environment variable "bell-style" must be set to
>   "none" for MSYS which comes with Octave.  There is two other options
>   "audible" and "visible".  Note that the "visible" setting seems to
>   produce the same result as "audible"  with Octiave 3.6.4 compiled with
>   visual studio and msys/bin/sh.exe version 3.1.17(1)-release
>   (i686-pc-msys).
>
> 1- You need to edit Octave-3.6.4\share\octave\3.6.4\m\startup\inputrc
>   2- Add this to the end of inputrc:
>
> `## Disable the beep!`
>   `set bell-style none`
>
> 3-  Restart Octave and check that it is disabled.
>
> I know in coming years some will find this thread and the procedure
>   will be a little different.  I bet the key will be finding the
>   "inputrc" file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no need for beep at all and the above does not work for you, you can fully disable it in the device manager (you must mark "show hidden devices" in order to see the non pnp driver).

[image]